# Using browser XMLSerializer() to produce XML without XHTML entities

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xmlserializer

I'm using XMLSerializer() to output an in-memory XML document, however it seems to 'entitizing' elements using XHTML standard entities like &nbsp ; . **I want to produce an XML document without XHTML entites**.

My target DTD does not define these entities, so if a user happens to input a character w/ a corresponding XHTML entity, the serialized document is not well-formed (references an undefined entity like &nsbp;)

Maybe I'm building the DOM tree incorrectly? Or is there another way to avoid XMLSerializer() behaving as if it were XHTMLSerializer()?

Comment: Maybe you could include a jsfiddle with an example of the XML you are trying to serialize. What you are describing should only happen, if you have <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> or the DOCTYPE set to use XHTML.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, didn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

worksforme in Firefox 38:

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.createRange()
    .createContextualFragment('<div foo="bar&quot;bar">&nbsp;&uuml;</div>'))
```

result:

```
"<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" foo="bar&quot;bar"> ü</div>"
```

Only standard XML entities and utf-8.